# ms08_067_netapi exploit & pivoting problem

Tags: windows, metasploit, smb, pivoting

I'm having troubles with ms08_067_netapi.

I have a private network with a web server (10.10.2.10), windows 7 (10.10.2.8) and windows XP (10.10.2.9). I'm hacking from outside the private network with kali (10.0.2.15) the web server then I make portforwarding to attack the windows 7.

The windows 7 attack is working but when I try to attack the windows XP with ms08_067_netapi exploit I can't get access and I don't know why.

Outside the private network the exploit works but why not inside when the pivoting is working for the windows 7?

This is my port forwarding list
[image]

My sessions

[image]

And my options
[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Copy/Paste and use the code formatting tool

Comment: Ok sorry i'm gona change the images. Thank you!

Comment: This looks more like a networking problem and not an exploit problem. Do pings work? Is there connectivity? What networking torubleshooting have you done?

Comment: Yes I have connexion between the web server and the windows XP, I supossed the problem was because the port forwarding was wrong but the exploit in the windows 7 works.

Comment: If this is a networking problem, then this falls outside our scope. You'll have to do a networking troublehsooting exercise.

Comment: Yeah if it is a networking problem yes but i though it could be some wrongly option when I make port forwarding or dunno. Thank you for your time!